# PHP skip row in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a while loop that outputs each database row to an array. Code:

```
$tickers = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $tickers .= $row['ticker'] . ",";
}
```

That works fine, however I want to skip past rows where $row['ticker'] == "-".

I have tried the following if statement within the while loop however it doesnt seem to work:

```
if ($row['ticker'] == "-"){
    continue;   
}
```

Any ideas?
Many Thanks

Comment: the only conclusion is that `$row['ticker']` is not equal to `-` or it works and you are mistaken....

Comment: If you placed that `if`-statement below the existing line in the `while`-loop, nothing happens - it has to be the first thing inside the loop.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't even select out those rows. `SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE ticker != '-'`

Comment: @jedifans Probably the best approach, indeed. If you can do it in SQL before PHP ever sees it, that makes for cleaner and more effective code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,

jedifans your answer worked perfectly, I was paying too much attention to the PHP i totally missed the SQL.

Thanks for the pointer.

For reference this is what solved my problem: SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE ticker != '-' –

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the loop as follows:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    if ($row['ticker'] !== "-") $tickers .= $row['ticker'] . ",";

}
```

Concatenation will only occur whenever this condition is fulfilled as !==.

Comment: @Lee Perkins, my code WILL work (so feel free to upvote it :)   ), but the cleanest solution is that of jedifans